# UISlider as TextField.inputView on iOS7

Tags: xcode5, ios7.1

I wanted to use a textField with an UISlider as inputView so that when I touch the textField the Slider shows up so that i can change the "value" of my textField. But my problem is: I don't know how to set the value that means I don't know a method that is called when I change the value of my Slider.
Could anyone help me? I would be absolutely pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a action for control event UIControlEventValueChanged.

example

```
UISlider *slider = [UISlider new];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSLog(@"New value: %f", slider.value); 
}
```